# Execute script as a specific user

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have a python script that does some file processing and need to run as a specific user. Seems on Unix this can be done by using os.setuid. How do I do that in python on windows?

Comment: It's an enviroment issue, I don't think you should be trying to do that from within the script itself.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do from within the script, but you can probably call the script using [`runas`](http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-runas-command-prompt/)

Comment: @CodyPiersall, by far your suggestion seems to be the best option. Please put this as one of the answer so I can at least upvote.

Comment: Anything for you, @user3885927. :)

Comment: See the accepted answer here as it is relevant: http://serverfault.com/questions/16886/is-there-an-equivalent-of-su-for-windows

Comment: @par, thank you for the link. In my case I do have the username/password of a generic account under which I want to run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do from within the script, but you can probably call the script using the [`runas`](http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-runas-command-prompt/) command; e.g.

```
runas /user:domain\username "python best_script_ever.py"
```

The potentially huge drawback with this approach is that you must supply the password when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

check if you are the specific user and if not do not run the python script. It can be done at least in the unix way by checking the `uid`, in windows you can use `wmic useraccount get name,sid` to get a users security identifier or in batch use `%USERNAME%`.

Comment: The question is specifically asking how to do it in Windows.

Comment: @par, my question is not about getting the current user's credentials or checking if he is a valid user. I just want it to be run as a specific user.

Comment: @user3885927 I am not sure if there is really a good way to do that unless you do something like I said make sure you are the user when you run the python script

Comment: @user3885927 I am trying to do it for the sake of least user inconvenience like entering the password as cody said